# What Framework/System/Tehnology to use for showcasing products but not sell them

Tags: framework

I have to build a website where I can give an admin panel to the admin from where he can add Products, Categories, Images for products, Descriptions etc. Just Imagine a Magento website to display all the products he can supply but not sell them online. With Brands, Categories and all that specifications.
My clients want just to showcase what he has to offer but not sell anything online. How to proceed here in the best possible way ?
I don’t want to reinvent the wheel so I am looking for some frameworks which can help me do this. Like a magento store but without the selling part.

Please tag me to the right place if I am not at the right place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: A kind of online catalogue right?